# Synchronize SwiftUI update with camera capture

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, camera

I'm building an IOS app that uses iPad's screen to project structured light on objects and uses iPad's front camera to capture photos at the same time.

I expect it to work this way:

1. UI displays pattern 1
2. camera captures a photo
3. UI displays pattern 2
4. camera captures a photo
5. UI displays pattern 3
6. camera captures a photo
7. ......

According to apple developer website (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/photo_capture/capturing_still_and_live_photos/tracking_photo_capture_progress), it is possible for me to monitor each step during the capture. So I write the code this way:

```
class ContentViewModel : NSObject, ObservableObject, AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {

    //Pattern to be displayed in the UI
    @Published currentPattern : UIImage

    init() {
        //Firstly, configure camera
        self.configureFrontTrueDepthCamera()
        //Then, prepare the first pattern
        self.currentPattern = ...
        //Finally, capture a photo
        self.capturePhoto()
    }
    
    //Configure camera
    private var frontTrueDepthCameraInput : AVCaptureDeviceInput!
    private let frontTrueDepthCameraPhotoOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()
    private func configureFrontTrueDepthCamera() {
        //omit
    }

    //Capture a photo
    func capturePhoto() {
        let photoSettings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
        photoSettings.isDepthDataDeliveryEnabled = true
        photoSettings.isDepthDataFiltered = false
        self.frontTrueDepthCameraPhotoOutput.capturePhoto(with: photoSettings, delegate: self)
    }

    //MARK: AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate protocol
    //Just before starting the exposure
    func photoOutput(
        _ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput,
        willBeginCaptureFor resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings
    ) {
        print("Before starting the exposure")
    }
    
    //When the exposure time begins
    func photoOutput(
        _ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput,
        willCapturePhotoFor resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings
    ) {
        print("When the exposure time begins")
    }
    
    //As soon as the exposure time completes
    func photoOutput(
        _ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput,
        didCapturePhotoFor resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings
    ) {
        print("As soon as the exposure time completes")
    }
    
    //When the photo output has image data available
    func photoOutput(
        _ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput,
        didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto,
        error: Error?
    ) {
        print("Photo is available")
        ......//Process the photo output
    }
    
    //When all of the system's work for a capture is complete
    func photoOutput(
        _ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput,
        didFinishCaptureFor resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings,
        error: Error?
    ) {
        print("Capture completes")
        //Prepare the next pattern
        self.currentPattern = ...
        //Capture a photo again
        self.capturePhoto()
    }
```

However, I found that SwiftUI isn't updated at the same time `currentPattern` is changed. There's a very short time interval between the change of a published variable and the change of the UI, and this is fatal for my program. Sometimes this app works this way:

1. UI displays pattern 1
2. camera captures a photo
3. camera captures a photo **(this should have happened AFTER the UI displays pattern 2)**
4. UI displays pattern 2
5. UI displays pattern 3
6. camera captures a photo
7. UI displays pattern 4

After reading some documents, I know that iPad's screen is refreshed at the rate of 60Hz. So I changed the last `photoOutput` function to:

```
    //When all of the system's work for a capture is complete
    func photoOutput(
        _ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput,
        didFinishCaptureFor resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings,
        error: Error?
    ) {
        print("Capture completes")
        //Prepare the next pattern
        self.currentPattern = ...
        //Sleep for 1/60 second, then capture a photo
        self.dispatchQueue.async {
            usleep(UInt32(1000000 / 60))
            //Capture a photo again
            self.capturePhoto()
        }
    }
```

But it doesn't solve the problem.

I want to make sure that the UI is displaying i-th pattern before the camera exposure time of the i-th photo begins. So, my question is, is there any way to synchronize UI update with camera capture? Is there some API that can notify my program if the UI finishes updating? Should I use SwiftUI or instead, use Metal to render the patterns?

Comment: You count with an async stream it would take some work but concurrency can do it.

Comment: You are capturing too often. Depending on your processing, it may take up to several seconds. So get the processing to notify when it's done, so you can capture the next frame only after receiving the previous. That is if it's important for you to have capture/processing steps each time. If it is not, then do what @loremipsum said. But even then, you need to find a pace that doesn't create too much work for processing, as your app will be slow, heavy, and will heat the device

Comment: @sfgblackwarkrts I'm sorry, but I don't understand what "get the processing to notify when it's done" means. In fact, in my code, the captured photo will be appended to a concurrent queue and be processed in other thread. The problem here is that SwiftUI is updated too slow, and I want to make sure that the UI is displaying the next pattern before the camera exposure time begins.

Comment: What I'm saying: you want to capture photo, process it, display it, and only afterwards capture the next photo, right? So capture photo -> sends to another queue for processing -> processing done, notify (who do you notify? view model probably) -> ui reflects the finished processing -> start capturing next photo

Comment: @sfgblackwarkrts I'm sorry that I didn't make my question clear. The patterns I want to display in the UI are prepared in advance (For example the program can load them from the disk at init time. They're irrelevant to the captured photos). The problem is that the program doesn't know when ui changes. I found that changing a published variable doesn't change the ui immediately: there is a short time interval between the change of a published variable and the change of the ui. As a result I don't know when to call capturePhoto() method.

Comment: @loremipsum Actually, ```@Published``` is not instant. If you place a mirror in front of the front camera, and capture a photo right after you change the published variable, you will find that the screen in the captured photo is still displaying previous UI.